# variable declaration inside a loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-management

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim j As Integer = 10
    Next
```

now my question is, Is memory allocated to j every time its executed inside for loop? or only value of 10 is assigned on subsequent iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's declared once per function and reset each iteration of the loop.

Same as this question:
[Does one of these use more resources than the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919655/does-one-of-these-use-more-resources-than-the-other)

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

This article might help you (variable scope and lifetime) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx